# One to One delete on cascade

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have 2 classes: Entry and Content.

```
public class Entry implements Serializable {
     @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     private Content content;
}
```

And Content have his values (name etc etc etc) ... What I want to do is if a content its deleted I want to delete any Entry ho its related with ...

This its not the tipical orphan problem (Im not deleting an Entry! Im deleting the Content)

Entry can have or not a content related with ... and the contents existenc are independient of the entrys ...

How can I say to hibernate "Hey ... if u are going to delete a content find any related FK and delete it as well!"

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating a link from Content to Entry as follows:

```
public class Content implements Seralizable {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, optional=true)
    private Entry entry;
}
```

Please note the optional attribute. This represents the fact that a Content might not have an Entry related to it as you said in your post.

Comment: I was talking about it with a co-worker and he said the same! Its not a bad idea but if i do this i have to create a FK in my content table ponting to an entry ??? I think this its not correct (or maby it is but im seeing it wrong) But I dont want to add the FK in my table (its feels wrong)! If i do not need to add the FK in my Content table and this its going to work "magically" then ... god bless u!

Answer (score 0):

Make the association bidirectional, and cascade the removal:

```
public class Content {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Entry entry;

}
```

Comment: I was talking about it with a co-worker and he said the same! Its not a bad idea but if i do this i have to create a FK in my content table ponting to an entry ??? I think this its not correct (or maby it is but im seeing it wrong) But I dont want to add the FK in my table (its feels wrong)! If i do not need to add the FK in my Content table and this its going to work "magically" then ... god bless u!

Comment: `mappedBy = "content"` means: the association is mapped by the other side of the association, using the foreign key in the entry table. You don't need any additional foreign key. Read the hibernate reference manual, because you MUST understand how associations work when using Hibernate.